# Laravel Eloquent, assert that collection contains item

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, phpunit

How to assert (in PHPUnit test) that Eloquent collection contains an item?

Something like this:

```
$expected = factory::create(Item::class)->create();
$eloquentCollection = someData(); // Item::orderBy(...)->...->get();
$this->assertContains($expected, $eloquentCollection);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the [`contains`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains) method to `assertTrue` the test as:

```
$this->assertTrue($eloquentCollection->contains($expected));
```

You may also pass a key / value pair to the contains method, which will determine if the given pair exists in the collection:

```
$this->assertTrue($eloquentCollection->contains('id', $expected->id));
```

Comment: Yes, looks like it works. But it is more messy :( I thought there are already built-in asserts for that.

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in function for this. And it is how we mostly do assertion. Somehow I find it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of PHPUnit (8.5, 9.6, 10.4) there is `assertContains`.

```
$needle = 'a';
$haystack = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$this->assertContains($needle, $haystack);
```

https://docs.phpunit.de/en/8.5/assertions.html#assertcontains
https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.6/assertions.html#assertcontains
https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.4/assertions.html#assertcontains